# NetworkX: BFS from multiple sources?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, traversal

Is there a way to run a BFS in NetworkX from multiple sources? I have looked through the API and Google, but I've not found any way to easily accomplish this.

Comment: You could augment the graph with a new node that is connected to the desired source nodes.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a way with any function available in [Breadth First Search](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html#module-networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search) from the NetworkX API, they all start from a single source.

Performing BFS on multiple nodes is trivial though, for whichever function you want to use, it's just a matter of iterating over the source nodes from which you want to perform a BFS. As a simple example, using `nx.bfs_tree`:

```
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10, 0.2)
[list(nx.bfs_tree(G, node)) for node in [1,4,5]]
# [[1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 4, 6, 9], [4, 2, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7], [5]]
```

Comment: Sure, though it would probably require fewer lines of code added to networkx than it would to parse that answer. Assuming BFS uses a queue, adding a list of nodes to that queue at the start would be sufficient.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying that there doesn't seem to be a way I'm networkx @ross agree that it would be simple to extend

Answer (score 0):

Networkx has another function for bfs call `edge_bfs`. This function yield the edges of G in a breadth-first-search order continuing until all edges are generated.
For example:

```
nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3]
edges = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
list(nx.edge_bfs(nx.DiGraph(edges), nodes))
```

the result of above code is:

```
 [(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

[according to networkx document](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.edgebfs.edge_bfs.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.edgebfs.edge_bfs), The naming of this function is very similar to bfs_edges. The difference is that ‘edge_bfs’ yields edges even if they extend back to an already explored node while ‘bfs_edges’ yields the edges of the tree that results from a breadth-first-search (BFS) so no edges are reported if they extend to already explored nodes. That means ‘edge_bfs’ reports all edges while ‘bfs_edges’ only report those traversed by a node-based BFS. Yet another description is that ‘bfs_edges’ reports the edges traversed during BFS while ‘edge_bfs’ reports all edges in the order they are explored